# How to optimize my current Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have written a query, which works correctly. But it takes more time to execute. I can't understand how can I optimize my current query.

Here will be thousand or million data. Like dislike table every user per like/dislike a new row inserted.

My query:

```
  select i.id,i.category,i.url,i.upload_by,i.upload_date,
(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `ulike`='1' and `imageid`=i.id) AS 'allLike',
(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `ulike`='1' and `imageid`=i.id and i.category !='4' and FROM_UNIXTIME(performdate)>= NOW() - INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS 'daytotalLike',

(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `ulike`='1' and `imageid`=i.id and i.category !='4'  and FROM_UNIXTIME(performdate)>= NOW() - INTERVAL '7' DAY) AS '7daytotalLike',
(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `ulike`='1' and `imageid`=i.id and i.category !='4'  and FROM_UNIXTIME(performdate)>= NOW() - INTERVAL '30' DAY) AS '30daytotalLike',
(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `ulike`='1' and `imageid`=i.id and i.category !='4'  and FROM_UNIXTIME(performdate)>= NOW() - INTERVAL '90' DAY) AS '90daytotalLike',
i.status from `image` as i, `like_dislike` as  likeDislike
WHERE i.status='approved' and i.id=likeDislike.imageid and FROM_UNIXTIME(likeDislike.performdate)>= NOW() - INTERVAL '90' DAY
    GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY '90daytotalLike' DESC Limit 50
```

[sqlfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8185/3/0)

Comment: Can you add your `CREATE TABLE` statements to this please, and what indexes you have. It would be better to format this SQL so we can see the broad structure as well - make life easier for your readers. Upvotes for a SQL Fiddle that people can play with.

Comment: Also, let us know (roughly) how many rows each table has, and what time the query is taking to run. If you can generate an explain plan, that might help you too.

Comment: @halfer sqlfiddle demo added.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: You try to do too much in one query. As far as I can see you want to know for all users, which 50 users had the highest scores on many variables. Yeah, sorry, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

So, get rid of all the subqueries, and leave one main query. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as 90daytotalLike,
  image.id,
  image.category,
  image.url,
  image.upload_by,
  image.upload_date,
  image.status 
FROM 
  image, 
  like_dislike
WHERE 
  like_dislike.ulike = 1 AND
  image.category != 4  AND
  image.status = 'approved' AND 
  image.id = like_dislike.imageid AND 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(like_dislike.performdate) >= NOW() - INTERVAL '90' DAY
GROUP BY image.id 
ORDER BY '90daytotalLike' DESC Limit 50
```

And if you need to know data for any of the other periods, run a seperate query.

Another method to lower the load on your database is to store the total likes in the database with your user. It's just a simple counter, nothing fancy, but it will safe you having to summate the likes all the time.

You can have counters for periods as well, simply update each counter when a vote expires.